# Styling and interface problems with a bootstrap search site

Tags: html, navigation, bootstrap-5, nav, sidebar

Over the past couple of days, I have been trying to program a search interface for a website using bootstrap, php, html, css and js. I have made a functioning top bar that is collapsible on mobile, but my sidebar is just a div, not a nav element and I dont know how to make it function in this way: I want it to take up a portion of my screen on the left on desktop and not be collapsible, but on mobile it should take up about half, be collapsible with a button it the bottom and not push any content, but rather overlay over the rest of the pages content. This is the sidebar code so far:

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary d-block d-md-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="sidebar">
        Toggle Sidebar
      </button>
      <div class="sidebar collapse d-md-block" style="margin-top: 58px;" id="sidebar">
Sort by
<h2>Filters</h2>


  <div class="card card-body">
  <b data-toggle="collapse" href="#filter1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Filter 1
</b>
  <div id="filter1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox1"name="filter1_checkbox1">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox2"name="filter1_checkbox2">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter1_checkbox3"name="filter1_checkbox3">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox3">Checkbox 3</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card card-body">
  <b data-toggle="collapse" href="#filter2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Filter 2
</b>
  <div id="filter2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter2_checkbox1"name="filter2_checkbox1">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter2_checkbox2"name="filter2_checkbox2">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="filter2_checkbox3"name="filter2_checkbox3">
  <label for="filter1_checkbox3">Checkbox 3</label><br>
  </div>
</div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Here, it takes up just 2 portions of the screen and looks decent on desktop, but once I collapse it to mobile, the button to show the sidebar isnt there and its just too small. Thank you guys for your help, I hope I have explained it alright.